# Casting struct ProcessSerialNumber to UnsafePointer<Void>

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift

I have a `ProcessSerialNumber` and want to create a `NSAppleEventDescriptor` from it, the same way as shown in [issue 14 of objc.io](https://github.com/objcio/issue-14-sandbox-scripting/blob/master/Scriptinator/AppDelegate.m#L50-L51). However the constructor expects an `UnsafePointer<Void>`.

```
let psn = ProcessSerialNumber(highLongOfPSN: UInt32(0), lowLongOfPSN: UInt32(kCurrentProcess))

let target = NSAppleEventDescriptor(
                 descriptorType: typeProcessSerialNumber,
                 bytes: &psn, // <-- this fails
                 length: sizeof(ProcessSerialNumber)
             )
```

What am I missing to convert it correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yet another glorious swift error message failure, the real problem is that typeProcessSerialNumber is an Int and the initializer expects a DescType.  Use:

```
let target = NSAppleEventDescriptor(descriptorType: DescType(typeProcessSerialNumber), bytes:&psn, length:sizeof(ProcessSerialNumber))
```

Comment: As pointed out by Martin, you also need to change psn to a var.